Kafka reactor response
My team is developing a chat application that uses Kafka Reactor for the transamition of data between the clients.
One of our problems is the return of feedback to the users. By calling an API like ex. "/registerUser" one would expect to recieve a feedback of whether the registration process has been successfull or not from the same endpoint without having to than call another one to find out the result, which is how kafka seems to handle things.
I'm new to working with kafka and just started bashing my head against it. Am I trying to do something that isn't possible or I'm looking at this wrong?

Kafka isn't exactly good for chat apps. It's asynchronous, by nature, so you shouldn't synchronous request-reply of HTTP... Try using something built over XMPP

Let me help explain how to handle this scenario effectively with Kafka Reactor in a chat application.
What you're looking to achieve is definitely possible. Here's a solution using Spring WebFlux with Kafka Reactor that provides immediate feedback:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, UserRegistrationEvent> kafkaTemplate;
    
    @PostMapping("/registerUser")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<RegistrationResponse>> registerUser(@RequestBody UserRegistration request) {
        return Mono.create(emitter -> {
            // Create a correlation ID for this registration
            String correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            
            // Create registration event
            UserRegistrationEvent event = new UserRegistrationEvent(
                correlationId,
                request.getUsername(),
                request.getEmail()
            );
            
            // Send to Kafka and listen for response
            kafkaTemplate.send("user-registration", correlationId, event)
                .addCallback(
                    success -> {
                        // Registration sent successfully
                        emitter.success(ResponseEntity.ok(
                            new RegistrationResponse(correlationId, "Registration in progress")
                        ));
                    },
                    failure -> {
                        // Failed to send registration
                        emitter.error(new RuntimeException("Failed to process registration"));
                    }
                );
        });
    }
}


Spring-kafka already has ReplyingKafkaTemplate... Why wrap a mono? Also, this isn't using Reactor Kafka at all
